# (C++) is member function slower than free function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, class, system

i was solving algorithm problems and wondering why my code is about twice slower than others even the logic was same.
Then i figured out using lambda or free function is much faster than member function.
i googled about it but most of the people says there are no difference.

i checked excution time on my computer, the results are below:
its a simple fibonacci function within/without class. Member function is about 0.3sec slower than free function.

```cpp
class bma{
public:
    int dfs(int a){
        if(a <= 1) return 1;
        return dfs(a-1)+dfs(a-2);
    }
};

int dfs(int a){
    if(a <= 1) return 1;
    return dfs(a-1)+dfs(a-2);
}

int32_t main(){
    bma bm;
    time_t start,end;
    double result;

    for(int T=1; T<= 5; T++){
        start = clock();
        bm.dfs(42);
        end = clock();
        result = (double)(end-start);
        cout << T << "th class func exec time:" <<  result/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    }

    for(int T=1; T<= 5; T++){
        start = clock();
        dfs(42);
        end = clock();
        result = (double)(end-start);
        cout << T << "th norm func exec time:" <<  result/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    }
}
```

[image: execution result]

is there something i don't know about C++ or process of calling a function?

Comment: It really depends on quality of implementation (e.g. of your compiler).    Generally speaking, it is better to compile with optimisation if you care about speed (among other quality metrics).    By default, however, compilers often default to building without optimisation, because that makes debugging easier - and testing performance of unoptimised code is rarely worth while.

Comment: And, BTW `int32_t main()` is a no-no.   `main()` returns `int` and `int` is not necessarily the same as `int32_t`.

Comment: Optimizations aside, the calling convention for non-static member functions involves pushing the pointer to your object onto the callstack, which might explain the difference.  I'm not 100% sure if full optimizations will detect `this` is unused and wrap the recursion as static calls.  You should look at your program's disassembly to understand the difference.  Ensure optimizations are on, and if there's still a difference it's probably the calling convention or a caching thing.  If you want accurate timing information, use `<chrono>` instead of archaic `clock()` calls.

Comment: @paddy - Considerations like calling convention versus optimisations based on recognising `this` is unused (or other things relevant to optimising code using member versus non-member functions) are quality of implementation issues.

Comment: Thank you so much, i gave the compiler optimization option and the result is no difference between two. I never thought it was about optimization. Thank you.

Comment: @paddy -- "the calling convention" depends on the compiler; at one time (I haven't kept up) Microsoft's compiler held the `this` pointer in a register, so there was no work involved in passing it to a member function.

Comment: @paddy `the calling convention for non-static member functions involves pushing the pointer to your object onto the callstack`. I would have thought that keeping the `this` pointer in a register would be more efficient. I am surprised the ABI does not use a register for the `this` parameter as it is always around.

Comment: @MartinYork It is only around when you need it